# A freshly recorded Selenium IDE test does not find an item 9 of 10 times

Tags: selenium, ide

I save a test and running it doesn't work most of the time.
I have tried waiting, clicking on the parent, looking for iframes that may not have been identified, etc. Although I am a beginner in Selenium I have made multiple similar accesses to other websites without major problems.
Attached screenshot of the test.

It seems that the error is due to the fact that the code executes a function that shows the field, ‘user' and ‘password’, however, I cannot identify what makes that function execute.

Any help would be welcome.[Selenium IDE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5U4A.png)Thank you

Example code in VBA

```
Obj.Start "chrome", ""               
Obj.Get https://www.bbva.es/empresas.html
Obj.Actions.MoveToElement(Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/button")).Perform  button
Obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/button").Click

Obj.Window.Maximize
         
element = Obj.FindElementByCss("div:nth-child(3) > .header__actions__item__link")
Obj.Actions.MoveToElement(element).Perform
Obj.FindElementByCss("div:nth-child(3) > .header__actions__item__link").Click

'I try to insert the data but <<<<<<here it cannot find the element>>>>>>
Obj.FindElementByClass("cod_emp").Click
Obj.FindElementById("cod_emp").SendKeys ("EMPCODE")
Obj.SwitchToFrame (Obj.FindElementByClass("iframe__base"))   

Obj.FindElementById("cod_user").Click
Obj.FindElementById("cod_user").SendKeys ("CODUSER")
      
Obj.FindElementById("eai_password-descrip").Click
Obj.FindElementById("eai_password-descrip").SendKeys ("PASSWORD")
 
Obj.FindElementById("cms-auth-business__submit").Click
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Additional informations on what you're trying to achieve and how could help others answer your question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution to the problem so I solved it in an alternative but less safe way.
I used the tab advance to position myself over the field, which activates the code that enables it and allows access to it.
Since it is a very risky solution, since it is easy for the order of the fields to be changed frequently, if someone knows the solution to the original problem, I would be very grateful.